# How can I demand access to a Windows share in a .NET thick-client app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, network-share

We have a thick-client that needs to access resources on a share where a client may not be logged on. The client might be on a Windows domain or it could be a mixed environment without a domain, so the user would have to log on to the server locally. In the past, one work around was to create a shortcut on the user's desktop to the share, which opens Windows Explorer, which opens a password prompt that grants or denies access to the share. How can I get the user to signon to the share without relying on Windows Explorer? What does Windows Explorer do that I can have my app do to demand access to the share?

I have read [Access files from network share in c# web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346/access-files-from-network-share-in-c-web-app), but I am doing this in a WinForms app and want it to be interactive. I have also read [How to prompt for a Password](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToPromptForAPassword.html), but that code just prompts for strings from the user rather than invoking the UI that demands and grants access to the share. I would rather not have my app know the user's password as much as trigger the OS to demand access for the network resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the Win32 API CredUIPromptForCredentials ( or CredUIPromptForWindowsCredential if you're running on Vista/Win2k8, you should check the winver to decide which call to make).

This method actually invokes the regular credentials prompt but you get the credentials (awful, I know).

PInvoke.Net has [sample code](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui/CredUIPromptForCredentialsW.html) showing how to call this function from C# (in the PInvoke sample you have to pass CREDUI_FLAGS.DO_NOT_PERSIST for flags if you've specified false in save. Weird, I know).

More info (and a unmanaged sample) on the great [Keith brown wikibook](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToPromptForAPassword.html) on security

Once you get the credentials (in a secure string) you can then impersonate the user to get to the resource (using logonuser).

And it's ugly. I understand you want Windows to show the standard prompt dialog and you don't want to know about the credentials.

I'm wondering if a ugly hack like using System.Diagnostics.Process to launch a hidden explorer.exe on the remote UNC would not do the trick. You'd have to find a way to wait for the user to have entered the credentials and then kill the spawned explorer process.

Comment: Hi Yann, thanks for the quick response, but didn't I reference the same Keith Brown page which uses the Win32 API CredUIPromptForCredentials in my original question? Isn't the example from PInvoke.NET the same one I already tried from the Keith Brown site. Except for the fact that the PInvoke.NET sample code yields an ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER result, the call looks the same to me.

Comment: I edited my post (including directions on how to make the PInvoke sample code work). But it's not really what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yann. But I found my answer in another SO question. Code here:
http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs