# Saving a file to another server

Tags: asp.net

What kind of path would I use to save a file (.pdf) on another server/network drive?
Say I have rights to a network drive 'optamail1' and a folder there called datasheets. I can access this folder from "Run" using `\\optamail1\datasheets\`, however, this kind of path will not work in my application. Has anyone tried doing this before?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Why won't this path work in your application? Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: why would it not work in your application?

Comment: See the comments to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940529/how-can-i-demand-access-to-a-windows-share-in-a-net-thick-client-app/940757#940757

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to grant access to the network share to the user that the ASP.Net application is running as.

Comment: Lol..dang I feel dumb. Dealt with all that doing ldap stuff..should have known. thx!

Answer (score 0):

To save "report.pdf" at "\optamail1\datasheets\", you would just use the path "\optamail1\datasheets\report.pdf" as normal. You should enclose the save operation inside a try/catch and check for exceptions in case: the path doesn't exist, net is down/computer not accesible, or you don't have permission to write on that path.