# How to save a file as a different user

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to run a windows forms app as the logged in user, but make the app save files using different user credentials?

I know the following is incorrect, but what I mean is something along those lines:

```
var userWithPrivileges = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, overwrite: true, userWithPrivileges);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need the [ImpersonateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) call. Note that you can't "just" save as that user, you need to have security access to that user in the first place - or it'd be quite a security leak if anyone could pretend to be anyone else with 2 lines of code!

So you'll need a security access token representing that user, usually obtained through a call to LogonUser, the MSDN link gives sample code.

Comment: [Here is a good code example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c/2563809#2563809) of how to do it.