# Save XML file to protected folder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am saving an XML file using the following code.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(submitOrder.GetType());
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, submitOrder);
}
```

Submit order is the C# DTO class.
If my file path is protected, how can I provide user name and password when saving the XML

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c)?

Comment: What you are looking for is [impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/754438) solution.