# windows authentication auto login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have link to local network server which requires windows authentication . How to do this automaticly from asp.net page?

Answer (score 0):

See [Access files from network share in c# web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346/access-files-from-network-share-in-c-web-app)

But the better way is to use your own win-service between ASP.NET and local network server.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Impersonation and deny unauthenticated users.  Then the users will be able to access the network server IF they have permissions to the server, and to the specific files/folders on the server.  Note that if you are using a File Share that permissions need to be set on BOTH the file share AND the underlying files and folders for users to access them.

If this is an Intranet app, then I would suggest configuring the entire ASP.NET app to use impersonation.  If you need to impersonate only for access to the network file share, try one of the options here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx